# How to use documentation template from another project

Tags: templates, documentation, enterprise-architect

I'm using enterprise architect 15 to generate documentation via Publish/Report Builder/Generate documentation. There, I see I can use templates:

[image]

I want to use a template that I used in another project, but it's unclear to me how to properly export it from another project and import into this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export and import templates using the *Reference Data Import/Export* feature.

### Export

**Configure | Model | Transfer | Export Reference Data**

[image]

Select the the templates you want to export.

### Import

**Configure | Model | Transfer | Import Reference Data**

[image]

Make sure to select the **Document Templates** dataset to import.

### MDG file

An alternative to this import/export is to include the templates in an MDG technology file. See the [manual](https://sparxsystems.com/enterprise_architect_user_guide/15.0/modeling/mdgtechnologies_2.html) for more info.